# Creating new Resource by Copying Existing resource

Tags: wso2

In WSO2 gov. registry 4.6.0 I have a resource called 'Project' which has many fields and a lot of data. I want to create multiple projects most of which have the same data as my first project but a few fields change.

I copied the resource using the 'resources->Browse' option and then renamed and moved the copied project under the projects location. I thought this would do the job but I noticed that the resource name is not the new name. It still shows the old project name as the resource name which I cannot edit as I get error (Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method editArtifact).

I also noticed that while using the 'resources->Browse' option the new project name shows up in the browsed directory but not in the actual project when I navigate to the project using the project link.

Is there a way to copy, duplicate and modify an existing resource without having to manually redo all fields in an existing resource again?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [Check-in Client](http://docs.wso2.org/display/Governance460/Check-in+Client) provided by WSO2 Governance Registry.

You can checkout the registry to your file system, do changes and check-in those back to the registry.

I hope this helps.